# What is the functional equivalent of Windows Communication Foundation in Java 6?

Tags: java, wcf

What is the functional equivalent of [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) in Java 6?

Comment: This is apples and oranges.  Your question is comparing a library (WCF) to a language/platform (Java 6).  I'd say it would be better to ask which Java libraries compare to .NETs WCF library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WCF offers several communication options. A nice presentation is [this white paper](http://www.davidchappell.com/articles/white_papers/WCF_Diversity_v1.0.docx) by David Chappel. There the following options are described:

- Interoperable Communication using SOAP and WS-*
- Binary Communication Between WCF Applications
- RESTful Communication
- Communication using POX, RSS, and ATOM
- Communication with Line-of-Business Applications using Adapters
- Communication via Message Queues
- Communication via Windows Peer-to-Peer Networking
- Communication Between Processes on the Same Machine
- Custom Communication

Although some options are not relevant to Java (e.g. the second one), it may help you to identify the corresponding functional equivalents in Java.

Comment: not an answer, more of a question clarification... should probably be a comment to the question

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what all WCF contains, but [JAX-WS](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/) (and its reference implementation [Metro](https://metro.dev.java.net/)) might be a good starting point.

Some of the other [technologies in J2EE](http://java.sun.com/javaee/technologies/) may apply as well.

Answer (score -1):

[Apache Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/) is a good start for the web service part. If you need the messaging queue check out [Apache Qpid](http://qpid.apache.org/) other then that you will probably need to ask about the exact problem you are trying to solve in Java.